# How to write superscript in DIA(Ubuntu16.04)?

Tags: superscript, dia

I can only write typical text in DIA. I need to write superscript. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still struggles with this:
In Ubuntu 18.04, open a text field in Dia and type ^3 for superscript 3.

Comment: This doesn't work in dia 0.97